# Can an interface require a base class to be implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dependency-injection, interface

I have an abstract BaseRepository which handles basic CRUD operations.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<TrinityDbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository where T : class, IUniqueIdentifier
{
    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<TrinityDbContext> dbContextFactory) : base(dbContextFactory) { }
}
```

I created an abstract RepoServiceBase to add those CRUD operations to my services.

```
public abstract class RepoServiceBase<T> where T : class, IUniqueIdentifier
{
    private readonly BaseRepository<T> _repo;

    public RepoServiceBase(BaseRepository<T> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
}
```

But when constructing the service I get the following error:
Cannot convert from IProductRepository to BaseRepository

```
public class ProductService : RepoServiceBase<Product>, IProductService
{
    public ProductService(IProductRepository repo) : base(repo) { }
}
```

Is there a way to require IProductRepository to implement BaseRepository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to require IProductService to implement BaseRepository?

No, you can't do this.

But you can create additional interfaces to handle that.

Create interfaces for base repositores:

```
public interface IBaseRepository
{
    // methods
}

public interface IBaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository
{
    // methods
}
```

Implement these interfaces by base repositories:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IBaseRepository
{
    protected readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<TrinityDbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository, IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IUniqueIdentifier
{
    public BaseRepository(IDbContextFactory<TrinityDbContext> dbContextFactory) : base(dbContextFactory) { }
}
```

Now your product repository stuff should look like this:

```
public interface IProductRepository : IBaseRepository<Product>
{
    // methods
}

public class ProductRepository : BaseRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    // implementation
}
```

Change `RepoServiceBase`:

```
public abstract class RepoServiceBase<T> where T : class, IUniqueIdentifier
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository<T> _repo;

    public RepoServiceBase(IBaseRepository<T> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
}
```

You can ignore `IBaseRepository` interface (non-generic one) as you expect only generic version in constructor params.